# Whatsapp Input TextFieldForm style in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a TextField/ TextFieldForm that behaves exactly like Whatsapp? For example, I want to implement a functionality where my TextField expands as user has more lines of words. Here is my code:

```
 body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 70,
                  maxHeight: 78,
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF4A78FF),
                  border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            // minLines: 1,
                            maxLines: null,
                            style: GoogleFonts.alegreya(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            controller: messageController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.black12,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              if (messageController.text != '') {
                                setState(() {
                                  writeMessage = false;
                                });
                              } else {
                                setState(() {
                                  writeMessage = true;
                                });
                              }
                            }),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                          onPressed: () {
                            addMessages(true);
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                            scrollController.animateTo(
                              scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                              curve: Curves.easeOut,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            );
                          },
                          icon: writeMessage
                              ? const Icon(
                                  Icons.insert_photo,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  size: 37,
                                )
                              : const Icon(
                                  Icons.send,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  size: 37,
                                )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I tried this but it does not expands and it almost hides my words in the TextField. The context here is that I want to build a Flutter Chat App. Thank you for you help!

Comment: `Expanded` will expand it to fill the available space. you need something that CAN expand it if the need arises, `Flexible`, so, wrap the child in it.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
                     Flexible(
                      child:  ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints:  BoxConstraints(
                          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          minHeight: 30.0,
                          maxHeight: 250.0,
                        ),
                        child:  Scrollbar(
                          child:  TextField(
                            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            maxLines: null,                                    
                            controller: controller,
                            _handleSubmitted : null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0,
                                  left: 15.0,
                                  right: 15.0,
                                  bottom: 5.0),
                              hintText: "Type your message",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color:Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),                           
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: _handleSubmitted is the same thing with onSubmitted?

Comment: yes ,, its onSubmitted